# NGINX different certificates per IP address

Tags: nginx, ssl

I've got two IP addresses on one server and would like to serve different SSL certificates for each IP address. Is it possible to bind different SSL certificates based on an IP address using NGINX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL certificates are not assigned by IP address but by name, and nginx has supported SNI for a long time so you can have as many SSL certificates per IP address as you want as long as you issue them for names that resolve to the IP address. 
Create a virtual server per IP address:

```
server {
    listen    x.x.x.x:443 ssl;
    server_name    host.name;
}
```

and obtain an SSL certificate for host.name and assign it to the vhost - this is well documented.

Comment: Yes, that I know. But I need to show different certificates anyway. It's one of the CDN service rules - the server IP should serve website's certificate. If I create two servers with different IP addresses NGINX ignores them, takes the first project config next to default one and serves its certificate.

Comment: You should add your nginx.conf to the question and show how exactly you did your tests

Comment: Can you improve the question as this would seem to be an issue with the specific CDN you are using, or your understanding of its requirements.

Comment: Sure Nginx may support SNI. But we don't know if all the clients do. Nginx has to server some certificate to clients without SNI support, and asking if that can depend on the IP address is a very relevant question.